# Discord.js TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined, what to do?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

i wants to make `/mute command`, but have one problem with add role. On my line `await member.roles.add(muterole).catch(console.error);` write error:`cannot read property 'add' of undefined`. I do not know what to do. Please help me. My full code:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const Bot = new Discord.Client();

Bot.on("ready", () => {
    console.log(`Bot joined by ${Bot.user.tag}`);
});

Bot.on("message", async msg => {
    if (msg.author.bot) return;
    if (msg.channel.type === "dm") return;

    let Prefix = "/";

    if (msg.content.startsWith(Prefix)) {
        let massive = msg.content.split(" ");
        let cmd = massive[0];
        let args = massive.slice(1);

        if (msg.content.startsWith(`${Prefix}mute`)) {
            let member = msg.mentions.users.first();
            if (member) {
                //let member = msg.guild.member(user);
                let muterole = msg.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "Muted");

                await member.roles.add(muterole).catch(console.error);
            }
        }
    }
})

Bot.login('my token been hidden :)');
```

Comment: The `roles` property on your `member` object is `null` or `undefined`. You need to investigate why `roles` is not an object. Perhaps it is valid that `member.roles` can be `undefined` or `null`, in that case you need check for this to avoid `TypeError`s.

Comment: @ethane i newbie. how to check it??

Comment: if i do not add role, i check id of member. id is not empty. i write: `member.id` and is not null

Comment: @ethane, yes, member.roles is empty :( how to fix it?

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with the Discord.js API but make sure that the `member` object is what you need to get in order to update roles.

Comment: I think you need to grab the member via the guild. See https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/guild#guild-member-object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to `discord.js` [docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User) class `User`, which is represented by `msg.mentions.users.first()` entity here, does not have a property 'roles'

upd:
you might be looking for `msg.mentions.members.first()`, which is an entity of `GuildMember`.

Comment: and... i need write: `msg.guild.members(member)` ???